# Convert from date to epoch-Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to convert a date from a TextBox from date to epoch time so that I can insert it into Oracle DB.

I managed to convert from epoch to date as below, but couldn't find a way to convert it the other way.

```
SelectCommand="SELECT ID,
            COMPANY,
            FIRST_NAME,
            LAST_NAME,
            ID_NUMBER,
            (SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-JAN-1970','DD/MM/YYYY')
            +(TRAINING_DATE/60/60/24), 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM dual) AS TRAINING_DATE,
            (SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-JAN-1970','DD/MM/YYYY')
            +(TRAINING_VALABILITY/60/60/24),'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM dual) AS TRAINING_VALABILITY
    FROM CONTRACTORS
    ORDER BY COMPANY"
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to (or should) store an epoch time in an Oracle DB? Why not store the actual date? Let your applications convert it to epoch time if/when needed.

Comment: Don't write `(SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-JAN-1970','DD/MM/YYYY')+(TRAINING_DATE/60/60/24), 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM dual) AS TRAINING_DATE`, make simply `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-JAN-1970','DD/MM/YYYY')+(TRAINING_DATE/60/60/24), 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS TRAINING_DATE`

Comment: Note your local time zone. Unix epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC!

Comment: Oddly, this code of your works despite deliberately using the wrong format mask! : `TO_DATE('01-JAN-1970','DD/MM/YYYY')`.  However, the neatest way to write a literal date is the ANSI format: `DATE '1970-01-01'`.

Comment: You cannot *add* 2 dates as you are, though you can *subtract* them.

Answer (score 11):

Subtracting `DATE '1970-01-01'` from the value will give the number of days (and fractional hours/minutes/seconds) difference and then you can multiply by `24*60*60`:

```
(date_value - DATE '1970-01-01')*24*60*60
```

---

**Update**:

Typically, epoch time is measured from `1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC`. If your date is not in UTC then you will need to convert time zones.

For example, if your date has the time zone `Europe/Berlin`:

```sql
( CAST(
    FROM_TZ(
      CAST( date_value AS TIMESTAMP ),     -- Cast to timestamp
      'Europe/Berlin'                      -- Convert to expected Time Zone
    )
    AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'                     -- Convert Time Zone to UTC
    AS DATE                                -- Cast back to DATE data type
  )
  - DATE '1970-01-01'
)*24*60*60
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9943dfbb0200ea61d54af896fa25ae44)

Comment: Heres an example using the above method:  `select (TO_DATE('02-01-2018', 'MM-DD-YYYY') - TO_DATE('01-JAN-1970','DD/MM/YYYY'))*24*60*60 from dual;`

Answer (score 1):

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE CONTRACTORS
                                           SET COMPANY=:COMPANY,
                                               FIRST_NAME=:FIRST_NAME,
                                               LAST_NAME=:LAST_NAME,
                                               ID_NUMBER=:ID_NUMBER,
                                               TRAINING_DATE=(TO_DATE(:TRAINING_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE('01-JAN-1970','DD/MM/YYYY'))*24*60*60,
                                               TRAINING_VALABILITY=(TO_DATE(:TRAINING_VALABILITY, 'MM-DD-YY`enter code here`YY HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE('01-JAN-1970','DD/MM/YYYY'))*24*60*60
                                           WHERE (ID=:ID)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution which works correctly whether the input date, *in local time*, is during Daylight Saving Time (DST) or not.

```sql
SELECT Round((Cast(Sys_extract_utc( Cast( your_date_field AS TIMESTAMP )) AS DATE) - To_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24MISS')) *24*60*60) AS epoch FROM dual;

-- 'your_date_field'   
-- '20210112' -> 1610427600    (no DST)
-- '20210512' -> 1620792000    (DST)
```