# best way to determine if two epoch timestamps are on the same date in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-performance

I have a table that contains an epoch timestamp column(transaction_date), if I have two rows and I want to determine if they are on the same day; without converting them to date using to_date. how can I do that and what is the best way that takes less operations while determining it.

Answer (score 1):

An epoch "timestamp" is a number which should be generated by converting the date to `UTC` (if it has a timezone) and [subtracting the epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38055263/1509264) to give a number of seconds (or milliseconds) since the epoch.

Without converting to a date, you can just divide by the number of seconds (or milli-seconds) in a day and truncate to get the number of days since the epoch and then compare those values:

```
SELECT TRUNC( transaction_date / ( 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) FROM your_table
```

If the values given by two rows have an identical number of days since the epoch then they are on the same day.

Answer (score 0):

Using this transformation from timestamp to day, you can compare

```
SELECT 
        * (all but transaction_date), 
        (EXTRACT (DAY FROM (transaction_date))*24*60*60) transaction_day
FROM yourtable;
```