# Oracle SQL Query to Convert Unix Timestamp to date for Java

Tags: java, oracle

we have a Table which contains Last Published date of Pages. but the field type is number and Page's LastPublished date stored as UnixTimeStamp (13 digit number).
I want to generate report which contains lastday published items (Everyday more than 20pages will get publish).

If the field is date then i can query but its in Number format. So, kindly please help me to generate report.

Sample Table:

```
ID              Approved       Path                PublishedDate
----------------------------------------------------------------
206b50140aSTFL  approved       /LocaleFlags/Small  1502866591000
dc563a2db23RD   approved       /LocaleFlags/Small  1442230611000
```

Comment: What does Java have to do with this question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your timestamp is in milliseconds (since you say the unix timestamp is 13 digits) then divide by 1000 to get the number of seconds since the epoch and you can use `NUMTODSINTERVAL` to change that to an interval and add it to the epoch `TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00'`:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + NUMTODSINTERVAL( PublishedDate / 1000, 'SECOND' )
FROM   your_table
```

However, if you just want to find yesterday's pages then [convert that date to a unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38055263/1509264):

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  PublishedDate BETWEEN ( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 1 - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 24*60*60*1000
                         AND ( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 24*60*60*1000 - 1
```