# Oracle epoch date function for the previous month

Tags: sql, oracle, powerbi

I have my table with EPOCH date system, i want to select data from previous month only. I have googled a lot but the only results i find is related to datetime system. Can you please help?

I will use this SQL Query to import data to Power BI.

Comment: You either need to convert your epoch numbers to real dates and compare with your date range as dates; or convert your date range to epoch numbers and compare as numbers. Up to you which way to go, though the latter is probably going to be more efficient. There are lots of examples of how to convert either way though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [convert your date range to an epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055178/convert-from-date-to-epoch-oracle/38055263#38055263) using `( date_to_convert - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 24 * 60 * 60` (assuming your epoch is in seconds since 1970).

You want to find values that are greater-than-or-equal-to the start of the previous month and before the start of the current month:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  epoch_column >= ( ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'), - 1 ) - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 24 * 60 * 60
AND    epoch_column <  ( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 24 * 60 * 60
```

If you use midnight of the last day of the previous month as your upper bound then you will miss all values that are on that last day but are after midnight.

Comment: Should be noted that Unix epoch is based on 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, local times might be considered

Comment: Thanks MT0, that worked perfectly as well!
What should i change to see the last week instead of last month ?

Comment: Assuming you are working on ISO weeks (Monday is the first day of the week) then from `TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY` to less than `TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )` (still subtracting the epoch, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a unix epoch (number of seconds since January 1st, 1970) to a date as follows :

```
TO_DATE('01/01/1970', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + epoch_column / 60 / 60 / 24
```

The division turns the epoch into a number of days, that can be added to the original date.

If you want to filter this on the previous month, then :

```
TO_DATE('01/01/1970', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + epoch_column / 60 / 60 / 24
    BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'mm'), -1) 
    AND LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'mm'), -1))
```

Or better yet :

```
epoch_column 
    BETWEEN
        ( 
            ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'mm'), -1) 
            - TO_DATE('01/01/1970', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
        ) * 60 * 60 * 24
    AND (
            LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'mm'), -1)) 
            - TO_DATE('01/01/1970', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
        ) * 60 * 60 * 24
```

This solution should be more efficient, as no operation is performed on the column being filtered, hence it should be able to take advantage of an existing index on `epoch_column`.